# What can I do about the long time it takes me to perform ablution?

Tags: salat, wudu

I have been facing problem in my wudu for a long time. It needs a lot of water and also takes a lot of time. I have tried many times to make it easier, but I often fear whether part of a limb becomes unwashed.  My clothes become wet and I need to change them.

My brother makes his ablution just in 1 minute and 30 seconds while I take 5 to 8 minutes. Not only in this, but also in using the toilet, and also while having [fard bath](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/37124/do-i-need-to-repeat-my-obligatory-bath-due-to-doubts-about-which-limbs-are-washe) the same things happen. All these things have become a matter of fear for me.

What can I do regarding this?

Comment: Ease up your mind the Prophet pbuh only poured three times water on him for ghusl, so don't make things more complicated than they are! So the most important thing is to get away these waswas. Maybe you should seek professional help! Note that wasting water is against the sunnah! See also http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/26139/is-it-permissible-to-re-use-the-water-that-has-been-already-used-by-myself-for and http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/5676/hadith-about-wasting-water

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this kind of bad whispers and you should stop follow it because of it endless and Satan guides you away from the right ablution (i.e. sunnah) way to fold your ability to pray.

Do your ablution **literally** don't care of "*often fear whether part of a limb becomes unwashed*".

Answer (score 0):

In addition to nagdawi's answer:

*انما العمال بالنیات*

The reward of deeds depends upon the intentions. Not that it doesn't matter if you get the ablution right or wrong, but more than anything what matters is that you realize who you are doing this for and why? Perhaps if you realize that you can move away from on the how.

The significance of the *why* is what really should be important to you. Let's look into The Dua during Ablution:

While washing the hands before performing Wudhu, one should say:
O Lord! Make me of those who repent and purify themselves.

While rinsing the mouth one should say:
*O Lord! Dictate to me the principles of faith on the Day I meet You, and make my tongue fluent with Your remembrance.*

While washing the nose one should say:
*O Lord! Do not deprive me of the fragrance of Paradise, and make me of those who smell its fragrance and per fume.*

While washing the face, one should say:
*O Lord! Make my face bright on the Day when the faces will turn dark. Do not darken my face on the Day when the face s are bright.*

While pouring water over the right elbow, one should say:
*O Lord! Give my book of deeds in my right hand, and a permanent stay in Paradise on my left, and make my reckoning an easy one.*

While pouring water over the left elbow, one should say:
*O Lord! Do not give my book of deeds in my left hand, n or from behind my back, nor chain it to my neck. I seek refuge in You from the Hell-fire.*

While performing the wiping of the head, one should say:
*O Lord! Cover me with Your Mercy, Blessings and Forgiveness.*

While performing the wiping of the feet, one should say:
*O Lord! Keep me firm on the Bridge (to Paradise) on the Day when the feet will slip, and help me in my efforts to do things which will please You, O' Glorious and Mighty!.*

Basically this wudu is to help us see ourselves in the presence of Allah and see the afterlife very close. It's purpose isn't to just do something. So if you're spending time on just getting right, I humbly suggest you spend time on thinking it right and humbling yourself before Allah. Don't let waswas hold you back from more important stuff. Islam isn't about just bending,kneeling,prostrating to Allah, It's much more about humbling while knowing exactly why you do it.

To see the full Arabic dua see [here](http://www.duas.org/wadhu.htm)